# Array: Convert table data to array by javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

For example I have something as below in HTML:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td class="getId">123</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="getId">345</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I'd like to create a for loop to loop over all the class name "getId" and store the words in an array so the output should be

> var new = ['123','345'];

how may I do this?

Comment: What did you tried yet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use jQuery **[`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/)** and **[`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/)** methods

```js
// iterate and generate custom element object
var res = $('.getId').map(function() {
  // get text 
  return $(this).text()
  // get result as array
}).get();

console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="getId">123</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="getId">345</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

With pure JavaScript use **[`getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)** get all elements and convert it to array using **[`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)**. To generate the text array use **[`Array#map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)**.

```js
var res = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('getId')).map(function(ele) {
  return ele.textContent;
})

console.log(res);
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="getId">123</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="getId">345</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use,

```
var arr = $(".getId").map(function() {
  return $(this).text();
}).get();
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/5842/)

Answer (score 2):

Using only javascript

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName('getId');
var _myArray =[]
for(var i=0;i<x.length;i++){
_myArray.push(x[i].textContent);
}
console.log(_myArray)
```

NOTE: You can also use `innerHTML` instead of `textContent`

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/vn7eo1ps/)

To use `forEach` property of array you can convert the `nodelist` to array by

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName('getId'); // document.querySelectorAll
var m =[].slice.call(x);
m.forEach(function(item){
_myArray.push(item.innerHTML)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

you can iterate using jquery as

```
var values = [];
$("td.getId").each(function(){
  values.push($(this).html());
});
```

**DEMO**

```js
 var values = [];
    $("td.getId").each(function(){
      values.push($(this).html());
    });

console.log(values)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
<td class="getId">123</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="getId">345</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

use Js without Jq :)

```
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="getId">123</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="getId">345</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
<script>
    var val = [];
    var list = document.getElementsByClassName("getId");
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        val.push(list[i].innerHTML)
    }
    console.log(val)
</script>
```